# how to wait for all request to finish?

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

how can i wait to all axios requests in loop will finish?

this is my code:

```
  async uploadMedia({ getters, commit }, payload) {
    await commit('setUploadLoading', true)

    const upload = new Promise((resolve) => {
      payload.forEach((item, index) => {
        const form = new FormData()
        form.append('file', payload[index])
        form.append('token', getters.getCustomerToken)
        form.append('no', index)

        this.$axios
          .post(`${process.env.API_URL}/visa/uploadfile`, form, {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
          })
          .then(() => resolve())
      })
    })

    await upload.then(() => commit('setUploadLoading', true))
    await upload.finally(() => commit('setUploadLoading', false))
  }
```

i make 2 requests in this loop, but i don't know how to wait until all requests to finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Promise.all`

```
 async uploadMedia({ getters, commit }, payload) {
    await commit('setUploadLoading', true)

    const upload = new Promise((resolve) => {
      const unresolvedPromises = [] // array of promises
      payload.forEach((item, index) => {
        const form = new FormData()
        form.append('file', payload[index])
        form.append('token', getters.getCustomerToken)
        form.append('no', index)

        const promise = this.$axios
          .post(`${process.env.API_URL}/visa/uploadfile`, form, {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
          })

        unresolvedPromises.push(promise) // push promise to array

      })
      const resolvedPromises = 
        Promise.all(unresolvedPromises).then(res => console.log(res)) // wait for all promises to be resolved
    })

    await upload.then(() => commit('setUploadLoading', true))
    await upload.finally(() => commit('setUploadLoading', false))
  }
```

docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: ```const resolvedPromises = await Promise.all(unresolvedPromises)``` await doen't work

Comment: @ShaSha you right sorry wrong syntax I fixed the snippets. try it now (: